# How to fill an AngularJS form loading data via XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input, xmlhttprequest

I have a form in an AngularJS controller, I would like to automatically fill the form with data collected with a *XHTMLRequest*.

Form has simply inputs with data-ng-model

**page.html**

```
<div id="PersonalAppID" data-ng-controller="PersonalAppCtrl as ctrl">
<form action="/" method="post" novalidate> 
<div class="input-group">
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
<label>First name: </label>
<input name="fname" type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.fname" placeholder="first name">
</div>
</div>
```

When controller init itself, it creates a request, downloads the data and put it into variables *ctrl.variable*

**page.js**

```
 angular.controller('PersonalAppCtrl',function() { var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.$onInit= function(){
            var req=XMLHttpRequest();

            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.status == 200&req.readyState==4){
                    var ret = convertJSON(req.responseText);
                    ctrl.fname = ret.FirstName;
                    return (true);
                }
           }
           req.open();
           req.send();
        }
```

My problem is that input are filled only if user touch an input and then touch outside it.
I'd like to have form filled **as soon as the page is loaded**.

I also tried to use *ng-load* and *ng-init* but the behaviour is pretty the same in this case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```
angular.controller('PersonalAppCtrl',function() { var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.$onInit= function(){
            var req=XMLHttpRequest();

            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.status == 200&req.readyState==4){
                    var ret = convertJSON(req.responseText);
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                       ctrl.fname = ret.FirstName;
                    });
                    return (true);
                }
           }
           req.open();
           req.send();
        }
```

You are making an XMLHTTPRequest which is a non angular code. Angular is not aware when the response is received so you need to make that angular aware by calling `$scope.$apply()`

Example:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        // AngularJS unaware of update to $scope
    }, 2000);
}
```

But, if we wrap the code for that turn in $scope.$apply(), the change will be noticed, and the page is updated.

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Waiting 2000ms for update";

    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.message = "Timeout called!";
        });
    }, 2000);
}
```

A very detailed explaination on this is given here - http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Its better to use Angular `$http` for all HTTP requests. So you dont have to bother about using `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: $scope.$apply worked perfectly in my case, thank you.

Comment: great! you're welcome!